# Source command error in Windows 10 on cmder

Tags: python, virtualenv, cmder

I am trying to use this command

```
source .venv\bin\activate
```

but I get this error

```
'source' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

can some one help me with this

Comment: I don't think, this is meant for `windows`, but specifically `*nix` platforms. For `windows`, i believe it is just running the `activate.bat` file

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bvirtualenv%5D+%27source%27+is+not+recognized+as+an+internal+or+external+command

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1.use cmd rather that cmder

2.to create env  use  "python -m venv <name_of_your_env>"

3.after this check if it created the environment or no by using "dir"

4.to activate the environment  use "<name_of_your_env>\Scripts\activate.bat"

5.to deactivate the environment  use "deactivate"

6.to delete the environment completely use "rmdir <name_of_your_env> /s"

You can also refer to this video if my explanation is not clear: https://youtu.be/APOPm01BVrk